# Loading an EditorFor template dynamically via Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, partial-views, editorfor

I have a Model object with a List collection of sub objects. I need to load the form fields for the sub object to the page, and provide a link to dynamically add form fields for a second object. So in other words, multiple sub objects can be created via one form and one post back.

My first thought was just to put the form fields in a partial view and load the view via Ajax.ActionLink. This worked but the problem comes in when trying to uniquely identify each object in the collection and bind the collection of objects on postback. For this it seems the correct usage would be to use an @Html.EditorFor() helper, but I don't know how to call that via Ajax to dynamically add the object's editor template to the page when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you were on the right track with regards to a partial view, you'll just need to  sort out the name property of your inputs so you can correctly bind to a collection of objects.

Have a look at [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) article by Phil Haack explaining how binding to lists works, or google for something more up to date with razor syntax.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I ended up using a partial view and a combination of the technique Phil Haack posted along with [this technique](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) to index my list items and keep track of insertions and deletions.